# Gvfs / samba lookup slow since update to 14.04

Tags: samba, cifs, gvfs

Ever since I moved from 13.10 to 14.04, I observe an annoying effect whenever a samba share is mounted to my work station. When I open Nautilus, or when I look up /run/user/1000/gvfs it freezes for several seconds. This is also the case when I choose "save as" from a program, as the file save dialog includes shortcuts to the mounted shares.

Have you also observed such behavior? Is there a way to debug it?

Comment: I experience the same issue on a clean install and filed the following bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/1363217 Perhaps it will receive more attention if you confirm you are affected by the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

Solving this problem has had mixed results.

If you try mounting DIRECTLY using CIFS, you'll see that it is about 3x faster. Compare CIFS to direct disc write.

[Many](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1578068) [people](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1429532) [have](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gvfs-list/2013-October/msg00007.html) [had](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/1236619) [this](http://www.overclockers.com/forums/showthread.php?t=736989) [problem](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=985823), [as](http://www.linuxine.com/story/slow-gvfs-samba-performance) [shown](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-850902-start-0.html) [by](http://markmail.org/message/t4lcpgxd6vvcmgkc) [a](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=262903) [quick](http://support.zenwalk.org/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=30740) [Google](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-desktop-74/smb-cifs-client-performance-when-connecting-to-shares-4175491292/) [search](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1645224).

Things said to work:

- [Some people have had success recompiling GVFS without HTTP.](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-6476846.html?sid=ce073f94a0368498c8dbd45665a1a221#6476846)
- [Others have been able to solve this problem by dumping Nautilus and using the commandline.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1578068&p=10118645#post10118645)
- [Directly using IP addresses instead of NAS can sometimes work.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1429532&p=8965004#post8965004)
- [Adding DirectIO to the `fstab`](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1429532&p=8974149#post8974149).
- [Changing the CIFS buffer](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1578068&p=11841064#post11841064) -- This is only temporary. To get this to be permanent, add `options cifs CIFSMaxBufSize=65536` to `/etc/modprobe.d/options.conf`
- [Actually using CIFS instead of GVFS](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-desktop-74/smb-cifs-client-performance-when-connecting-to-shares-4175491292/)

Comment: I did not have the time to try out all possibilities, but then I was asking for debugging hints in the original question. Even though I do not have a solution yet, I award the bounty to you rather than let it waste.

Answer (score 2):

Troubleshooting tips:

- Try a different user:

```
$ useradd testuser
```

- Reinstall program

```
$ apt-get reinstall gvfs
```

- Check from a LiveCD of 14.04 (last resort)

Sorry man, this should go as a comment (but I don't have enough karma *sigh*).

Comment: No worries, always a useful starter